# Maven: set property in pom.xml from properties file

Tags: maven

I have multi-module project with a lot of dependencies on different modules versions. At the moment versions are hardcoded and one needs to change them manually. So I decided to put all of them to a properties file and get properties values from it during project build.

Here is how I try to do it:

**root pom.xml**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <files>
                    <file>./version.properties</file>
                </files>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

**file version.properties**

```
module1.version=1.1
module2.version=1.8
module3.version=5.4
```

**example of module pom.xml**

```
<properties>
    <module1.project.version>${module1.version}</module1.project.version>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.mymodule</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>${module1.version}</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
```

Build fails with:

> Failed to execute goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin:1.7:parse-version
>   (parse-versions) on project ccm-agent: Execution parse-versions of
>   goal org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin:1.7:parse-version
>   failed. NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
>   execute goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin:1.7:parse-version
>   (parse-versions) on project ccm-agent: Execution parse-versions of
>   goal org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin:1.7:parse-version
>   failed.

How can I read some properties from a file and configure pom.xml in correct way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appeared to be very simple at the end. I used `initialize` phase. Changing it to `validate` fixed the problem:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>validate</phase>
```

Comment: Are you using Maven 2 or 3?

Comment: Maven 3.0.4. I think it matters?

Comment: @Dragon Could you please look at the below question I am unable to access the property file into the pom.xml https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51656393/error-while-reading-the-property-file-in-pom-xml

Comment: Not working with Maven 4, not able use the property read from property file as Version or project properties.

Answer (score 2):

You must not use properties / variable replacement inside of `<parent>` elements.

The main reason here is that Maven must read the parent POM before it can start expanding properties since the parent POM might define properties as well.

Comment: Maybe example is not as correct as it should be. But one can use it in dependencies, for instance.

Comment: I said "You must not use properties / variable replacement inside of `<parent>` elements". Dependencies are a completely different matter since they can't modify your properties.

Comment: I understood my fault in example. Thanks.

Comment: In fact, you should not use variables in any `<version>` element except for dependencies. Use `<dependencyManagement>` instead.

Comment: @AaronDigulla Can you please give an example for the above statement

Comment: @khan https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management