# Is maven capable to replace property placeholder ${prop} with value from .properties file

Tags: java, maven

I have a project created with maven. It is responsible for building war file. Is it possible that in some resources maven would change property placeholders `${prop}` in some resources to values from another `*.properties` file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maven Change a value in a file based on profile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335431/maven-change-a-value-in-a-file-based-on-profile)

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18574025/maven-set-property-in-pom-xml-from-properties-file

Comment: Thank you guys, I did not managed to get correct keywords for search :)