# How to set different version for all child in a multi module maven project setup

Tags: java, maven, build-process, versioning, multi-module

We have multi module project setup with a lot of dependencies on different modules versions.

```
ParentModule_16.3.0.1.0-
   ----ChildModule1_16.3.0.1.0
   ----ChildModule2_16.3.0.1.0
   ----ChildModule3_16.3.0.1.0
```

Earlier all versions were hardcoded in pom.xml for each module. Later we decided to get these versions from a property file. So i followed below link and it worked fine -

[Maven: set property in pom.xml from properties file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18574025/maven-set-property-in-pom-xml-from-properties-file)

now we have a scenario where we want to update version of
     *childmodule2_**16.3.0.1.0** to childModule2_**16.6.0.0.0** 
     and 
     parentModule_**16.3.0.1.0** to parentModule_**16.6.0.0.0*** 
and *rest remains unchanged*.

Now the issue we are facing is, when we do full build using parent's pom it doesn't pick jars of some modules because of old versions(16.3.0.1.0).

I have read some blogs where it says maven always pick latest versions.hence the older jars are not getting picked.and some says You always have to specify parent's version. Fortunately, it is inherited as the module's version what is desirable in most cases. Moreover, this parent's version declaration is bumped automatically by Maven Release Plugin.

Can some please help me to understand this. Is there any way to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Below is my Parent pom.xml

---

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
<artifactId>parent</artifactId>
<version>${parent-version}</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
    <module>chiled1</module>
    <module>child2</module>
</modules>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <files>
                            <file>version.properties</file>
                        </files>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <parallel>methods</parallel>
                <threadCount>10</threadCount>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Make assembly -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptor>${project.basedir}/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/dist</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>create-archive</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

---

child2 pom.xml

---

```
<groupId>com.myproject.child1</groupId>
<artifactId>child2</artifactId>
<version>${child2-version}</version>

<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${version}</finalName>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>initialize</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <files>
                        <file>../version.properties</file>
                    </files>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>

    </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

---

version.properties

---

Earlier -

parent-version=16.3.0.1.0

child1-version=16.3.0.1.0

child2-version=16.3.0.1.0

Now-

parent-version=16.5.0.0.0

child1-version=16.3.0.1.0

child2-version=16.5.0.0.0

Comment: If you have a multi module build the foundation idea is to have the same version in all modules for the modules themselfs. Apart from that if you use maven release plugin will also update all child module versions..otherwise there is something wrong...

Comment: But here idea is to update version of those moduls which got modified during current release. we do not want to update the version of unchanged or untouched modules.

Comment: If think about that way you need to make tests between the different versions of the modules if you get more different versions you need more tests...

Answer (score 1):

I think you are doing something dangerous.

The problem is that if I didn't get you wrong you are trying to build only some of your libs with new versions and some with old ones. In Maven usually if something has a non-SNAPSHOT version it's treated as "released" and hereby stable and it wouldn't try to update that ever again. So this could describe your observation of old versions being used.

Usually you would have your project in a 3.0.1-SNAPSHOT and work with that. In this case you would always get your updates.

Now there are other problems with this approach. You can release a new version with each module having it's own version without any problems. The problem is if you try to release something with a version you already used, things will blow up. Now you could restrict your Maven reactor to release only the modules you want to release and would avoid this problem. Unfortunately you would be running into the next problem as Maven would only update the versions of modules that are part of the current build. So in this case any SNAPSHOT dependency to a module that's not being released would stay a SNAPSHOT and the release plugin would fail for this.

A few years ago I had a customer with the need to release individual modules just the way you are describing it. I did solve the problem, but it wasn't easy. In short: I had to patch the release plugin by changing one or two lines of code, then I had to create a Jenkins Plugin to assist me with configuring the build as it now required an insane input on the commandline. I wrote down everything about :

- the release process here:
  https://dev.c-ware.de/confluence/display/PUBLIC/Releasing+modules+of+a+multi-module+project+with+independent+version+numbers
- the Jenkins Plugin here:
  https://dev.c-ware.de/confluence/display/PUBLIC/Developing+a+Jenkins+Plugin+for+the+Maven+Release+Plugin
- The code for the Jenkins plugin is located here:
  https://github.com/chrisdutz/jenkins-release-plugin

Comment: Thanks for your comment Christofer but i didn't totally get you. I am comparatively new to maven. i have attached my pom.xmls that i am using, please have a look if you can suggest something.
 idea is to update version of those moduls which got modified during current release. we do not want to update the version of unchanged or untouched modules

Comment: Ok ... so I was assuming that you knew maven ... if you don't I agree that understanding my answer could be a challenge. But the problem is that I probably shouldn't give you a full Maven training here. Actually I am currently working on finishing a Video Tutorial on Maven I gave at ApacheCon in Vancouver a few weeks ago.
I think you should have a look at how Maven handles versions. I doubt passing them in using variables is a good thing to do. During development you would probably have your modules in a Version with the suffix "-SNAPSHOT" and remove that as soon as you release a new version.

Comment: But i have 20 sub modules. if i don't put version in variables then i have to make change in all pom files every time we release a module.
Even if i do this, if my parent version set to 16.6.0.0.0 build will not pick jars lower than this version.

Comment: I would call a maven project with 20 modules a mid-sized module. I have some projects up to 100 modules. In maven you wouldn't have to manually update the versions if you use the release-plugin for example. For just changing versions throughout your project the versions plugin is a huge help.