# Error while reading the property file in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, maven-plugin, properties-file

I have a sample properties file as following.

sample.properties

```
language=English
site=www.google.com
login=Login
```

I am invoking the property file into my pom.xml using the following plugin and goal as

properties-maven-plugin and 
read-project-properties
my pom.xml is

```
             <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>initialize</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <files>
                                    <file>src/main/resources/sample.properties</file>
                                </files>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

But when I am accessing the same in the systemconfiguration I am unable to read them and getting an error

```
    <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                            <language>${language}</language>
                            <site>${site}</site>
                            <login>${login}</login>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Also the property tag as below is empty as the goal defined should read it and define it.

```
 <properties>
</properties>
```

And the Error as below

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'site' less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Inspects a Maven model for resolution problems
```

I am trying to access the pom.xml in the code as below.

```
String site = System.getProperty("login");
```

Comment: Is there good reason why you go such complicated way..just put the property file int `src/test/resources` and they can be used from your test code? Can you show the test code ....

Comment: Well the property file is created under resources section itself, I know they are other ways too like resource bundle or defining the same in the properties in Pom.xml,curiously know how it happens by loading the property file and how they are loaded into iproperty section.

Comment: Guys could anyone who me out?

Comment: @khmarbaise so the goal "read-projetct-properties" won't read the properties file into the pom.xml,could you please let me know.

Comment: @khmarbaise once the value is fetched into the pom.xml then I will be retrieving the value in the test using below " String language = System.getProperty(site");"